# Speeding up OS drive traversal

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, fs, traversal

I have created a program that recursively scans my hard drives for files.

There are nine drives on my PC, and the most complex drive is the OS/programs drive, the `C:` directory. It of course takes a lot longer to scan than any of my other drives.

Does anybody know any tricks that would allow me to scan this specific drive more efficiently, but just as thoroughly?

I know I can cache the results as a tree to speed up future scans of this drive, but is it in any way possible to speed up the initial scan?

```
async function scan(path, exts, persist) {
  try {
    const stats = await fsp.stat(path)
    if (stats.isDirectory()) {
      const
        childPaths = await fsp.readdir(path),
        promises = childPaths.map(childPath => scan(join(path, childPath), exts)),
        results = await Promise.all(promises)
      return [].concat(...results)
    } else if (stats.isFile()) {
      const fileExt = extname(path).replace('.', '')
      if (exts.includes(fileExt) && !path.includes('$RECYCLE.BIN')) {
        return {
          "path": path,
          "root": parse(path).root,
          "name": basename(path, fileExt).slice(0, -1),
          "type": fileExt,
          "size": stats.size
        }
      }
    }
    return []
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    return []
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use `worker_threads` to distribute your scanning, and then combine it in master

Comment: @Abhishekchandel is that an NPM package or? if im distributing the scanning (im assuming) amongst different threads, is it still possible to conduct the search asynchronously??

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v13.x/docs/api/worker_threads.html. this is in-built module in nodejs. You can run these worker threads in parallel(provided that mulitple cores are available). so yes. they will async in true sense

Comment: but would it in any way interfere with using asynchronous code/promises/async await/etc?